# What is causing this window to open, but not close?

Tags: windows

As you can see in this video, the window opens when I crank it, but won’t close when I go the opposite direction. It acts as though I’m taking out the crank itself. To close it, I have to remove the crank and manually pull the window shut. It seems as though the crank isn’t catching the gears when trying to close it.

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0lYMr0wTUo7KLKfWCiDHtP9yA#Wakefield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to close it, the cam screw in the unit backs out. That is the drive that will open and close the window. It should not unscrew out. There is some sort of nut or locking device on the end of it to keep it from backing and allowing it to close the window. That locking device is obviously broken. You might be able to disassemble the unit and fix the broken part. I think your best bet is to replace the opening device. Many home stores carry replacements and if you can find a name on it, you can probably get it online. Good luck and stay safe.

Comment: Yes, you appear to be correct! That makes sense as the entire crank mechanism shouldn't be coming out. I noticed a crack on the bottom of it just now where it must have broke off. I know the unit is quite old, but I found a replacement online, thanks!